# Missing properties/methods in ReceiptItem

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, bots, botframework, receipt

I've created a simple bot using MS BotFramework, it's enabled to the following channels: **WebChat**, **Skype** and **Facebook**.

The bot allows the user to select or search some products to add to an order, the issue is about the properties to pass to the receipt when it's created.

According to the [Facebook Docs: Receipt Template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/receipt/), it accepts the **currency**, **payment_method** and some other properties, but I can't find them in the [MS BotFramework Docs: ReceiptItem](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.receiptitem.html).

There is any way to add this properties?

Comment: what language, C# or Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReceiptItem` are going to be the items of the [ReceiptCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.receiptcard.html). The `ReceiptCard` also have a collection of [facts](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.receiptcard.html#facts), which is the place to provide additional things to display to the user, for example, the **payment_method**.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/bot/dialogs/checkout.js#L87-L100) is an example of how to use the `facts` collection:

```
        var receiptCard = new ReceiptCard
        {
            Title = Resources.RootDialog_Receipt_Title,
            Facts = new List<Fact>
            {
                new Fact(Resources.RootDialog_Receipt_OrderID, order.OrderID),
                new Fact(Resources.RootDialog_Receipt_PaymentMethod, creditCardOffuscated)
            },
            Items = new List<ReceiptItem>
            {
                new ReceiptItem(
                    title: order.FlowerCategoryName,
                    subtitle: order.Bouquet.Name,
                    price: order.Bouquet.Price.ToString("C"),
                    image: new CardImage(order.Bouquet.ImageUrl)),
            },
            Total = order.Bouquet.Price.ToString("C")
        };
```

Just in case, here is the same but for `C#`.